# Limit the height of the violin plot data within range

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

How can I make sure that violin plot contained within it's data range? I have binary classified feature categories (1,0). Within that values can range from 0 to 1. However as you can see when binary classification is 1 (orange). There is no values beyond 0.6. How can I fix that?

```
for f in binary_feature_name:
    x = master_df_copy['status']
    vfig = sns.violinplot(x=f, y='value',  data = eda_cis_df, palette='Set2', cut=0)
    fig = vfig.get_figure()
    fig.savefig('./output/eda/' + f + ".png") 
    plt.show()
```

[image]

I am expecting something like this

[image]

Comment: The second image are matplotlib's type of violin plots.  See e.g. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/customized_violin.html

Answer (score 0):

From https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html:

> cut: float, optional
>
> Distance, in units of bandwidth size, to extend the density past the extreme datapoints.
> Set to 0 to limit the violin range within the range of the observed data.